# DOMDocument loadHTML returns only one div

Tags: php, parsing, dom, domdocument

I am trying to parse HTML from a page, and access specific nodes from it. I tried with this code:

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen&all=1", false, $context);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$html = $dom->loadHTML($result);
```

The problem is that it only returns one div with a string inside, however I need the nodes as an object.

I also get many warnings because of bad HTML.

Comment: You should provide more information.

Comment: Could you provide the output of the URL?

Comment: When I open that URI:  http://zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen&all=1
All I get is an error message, "ERRROR: falsche Parameter übergeben"
Your problem is not the PHP, it's the URI you're trying to parse

Comment: Grammar changes

Comment: FYI, `DOMDocument#loadHTML` returns a boolean so I hope you weren't expecting `$html` to contain something else